# run two concurrent sessions with pgadmin

Tags: database, concurrency, pgadmin, transaction-isolation

I need to run two concurrent sessions (run two sets of transactions at the same time) against my database. Each transaction has its own begin and end transaction statements.

What statements do I need to use to tell my database to run two specific sessions concurrently, after I changed the transaction isolation level? I'm using pg-admin.

would the function pg_sleep help me run my two sets of transactions at the same time?

Thanks!